# How do I calculate the average number of guesses it took to guess a number, multiple times

Tags: java, average

So we are making HiLo in our java class im taking, and the instructions said that the player should be able to play more than once. So I have done that, and also calculate the average number of guesses it took to guess the number of ALL games, I have no clue how to do that since the number of guesses resets after the game resets?

I have the same problem with the time ( Exactly the same thing, the average time it took to guess the number)

I have tried writing guesses++ but I don't know how to "store" the number of guesses it took for each game and no clue how to do it

```
public class HiLo{

   //Globala-Variabler
   static int tal = 0;
   static int totaltSpelade = 0;
   static int gissning = 1;
   static int antalGissningar = 0;


   public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
      // val slingan


      int val = Kbd.readInt("\nKlicka 1 för 1-10\nKlicka 2 för 1-100\nKlicka 3 för 1-1000");


      if (val == 1){
         tal = (int) (Math.random() * 10)+1;
      }


      else if (val == 2){
         tal = (int) (Math.random() * 100)+1;
      }


      else if (val ==3){
         tal = (int) (Math.random() * 1000)+1;
      }
      else{
         Kbd.clearScreen();
         System.out.println("\nFelinmatning!");
         main(null);
      }


      // tid och gissnings slinga
      int gissningar = Kbd.readInt("\nBörja gissa!");
      long startTid = System.currentTimeMillis();


      slinga();


      //stop tid
      System.out.println("\nGrattis!\nDu gissade rätt tal på " + antalGissningar + " försök!");
      long stopTid = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long tid = stopTid-startTid;
      System.out.print("Det tog dig! " + (tid/1000) + "s");
      totaltSpelade++;


      int avsluta = Kbd.readInt("\nKlicka 1 för att köra igen\nKlicka 2 för att avsluta");
      if (avsluta == 1){
         //Kbd.clearScreen();
         main(null);
      }


      else{
         System.out.println("\nHejdå!, Det tog dig i snitt " +
         // THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO PRINT OUT THE AVERAGE NUMBER OF GUESSES OF ALL GAMES
         (antalGissningar/totaltSpelade) + " gissningar per gång.");

         System.out.println("\nOch i snitt " + (tid/1000) + " s");
         //Kbd.clearScreen();
         System.exit(0);
      }
   }

   // val slinga metod

   public static void slinga(){


      while (gissning != tal) {
         antalGissningar++;
         if (gissning > tal) {
            gissning = Kbd.readInt("\nLägre! ");
         } else if (gissning < tal) {
            gissning = Kbd.readInt("\nHögre! ");
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Also let me know if you have any feedback on my code, I want to improve!

Sidenote: The Kbd class is a class our teacher uses instead of scanner, so instead of 2 lines it's one line of code, pretty neat!

Comment: At least for me it is easier if variable names were in English.

Comment: You've already done calculating that average number of guesses, right? The only problem is that when the user restarts your program, everything resets. In that case, you could save that data to a file

Comment: After your while loop finishes, add the guesses for that game to a new field: `totalGuesses`, and increment another field: `totalGames`. Then anytime you want you can divide guesses by games. Also, I think I'd use a loop rather than calling `main` recursively.

Comment: @AjahnCharles We haven't really learned about fields yet so I have no clue how to do that,

Comment: @Goion tal = the number , totaltspelade = totalt games played, gissnings = guesses , antalGissningar= number of guesses , val = choice , starTid = start time and stop tid = stop time , avsluta = quit

Comment: @AjahnCharles What loop can I use to restart the program instead of using main(null)

Comment: @LeoLeontev Saving the data to a file? How and why? We haven't really talked about that yet

Comment: You can use two nested loop. Could be while or do while. One for the game itself and the other to allow user to play multiple times

Comment: @Goion Could you give me an example? We have touched nested loops a bit so I'm kinda lost.

Comment: [Nested Loop in Java](https://www.programiz.com/java-programming/nested-loop)

Comment: @Goion I don't really understand how to apply this while loop to my game, what should the while statement be equal to? while( ?? = ??) 

Sorry I this is a dumb question

Comment: while (userWantsToPlayNextRound). You can have an arraylist to track number of gusses in each round then you might not even need nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a guessing number game. The goal is to show you how to use nested loop instead of calling main method recursively. It might not follow all of your requirements. There are a lot of things that you can add like calculate average guesses based on difficulty level. Give hints, Make sure user enters a number within the range of difficulty level etc....

I have explained the logic in comments.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
   String playAgain = "yes";
   ArrayList<Integer> totalGuesses = new ArrayList<>(); // Keep track of total guesses in all rounds
   int round = 1; // Round number
   do {
      // Prints greeting
      System.out.println("Welcome to High Low game.\nPlease enter difficulty level.");
      System.out.println("Level 1: Easy Range [1-10]");
      System.out.println("Level 2: Medium Range [1-100]");
      System.out.println("Level 3: Hard Range [1-1000]");
      System.out.print("\nEnter Level Number: ");

      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      int difficultyLevel = scanner.nextInt();
      // Making sure that user inputs difficulty level within a certain range
      while (!(difficultyLevel > 0 && difficultyLevel <= 3)) {
         System.out.print("Please enter correct difficulty level: ");
         difficultyLevel = scanner.nextInt();
      }
      // Displays selected difficulty level
      System.out.println("Difficulty level is set to " + difficultyLevel + "\n");
      int theNumber = 0;

      if (difficultyLevel == 1) { // This part is copied from your code
         theNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 10) + 1;
      } else if (difficultyLevel == 2) {
         theNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      } else if (difficultyLevel == 3) {
         theNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 1000) + 1;
      }

      boolean hasGuessed = false;
      int numberOfGuesses = 0; // keep track of number of guesses in each round
      int guessedNumber;
      ArrayList<Integer> alreadyGuessed = new ArrayList<>();
      while (!hasGuessed) { // While user has not guessed (This while loop is nested in do while)
         System.out.print("Please guess the number: ");
         guessedNumber = scanner.nextInt();
         if (theNumber == guessedNumber) { // If user guesses correctly
            hasGuessed = true;
            numberOfGuesses++;
            System.out.printf("\nCongratulations you have guessed the number on your number %d attempt",
            numberOfGuesses);
            totalGuesses.add(new Integer(numberOfGuesses));
         } else { // If guess is incorrect
            numberOfGuesses++;
            alreadyGuessed.add(new Integer(guessedNumber));
            if (guessedNumber > theNumber) {
               System.out.println("\nSorry but the number you are trying to guess is lower that your guess");
            } else {
               System.out.println("\nSorry but the number you are trying to guess is higher that your guess");
            }
            // Prints already guessed so user doesn't enter same value. You can program so it doesn't accept same number by checking the guessedNumber againstalreadyGuessed
            System.out.println("Already guessed numbers: " + alreadyGuessed.toString());
         }
      }
      // when hasGuessed is true the while loop exits
      System.out.print("\nDo you want to play again? Enter yes or no: ");
      playAgain = scanner.next(); // Asking user if they want another round
      if (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("yes")) {
         System.out.println("\nRound " + ++round); //Prints round number plus adds empty line between each round
      }
   } while (playAgain.equalsIgnoreCase("yes"));
   // If player enters anything besides yes it exits do while loop
   double averageGuesses = calculateAverage(totalGuesses); // Calculates average guesses
   System.out.println("\nYour average number of guesses are " + averageGuesses);
}

/*
 * Adds all elements in array and divides it by arraylist size
 */
private static double calculateAverage(ArrayList<Integer> list) {
   Integer sum = 0;
   if (!list.isEmpty()) {
      // Iterate through list and stores each item in a variable (item)
      for (Integer item : list) { 
         sum += item; // short form of sum = sum + item;
      }
      return sum.doubleValue() / list.size();
   }
   return sum;
}
```

**Sample Output:**

```
Welcome to High Low game.
Please enter difficulty level.
Level 1: Easy Range [1-10]
Level 2: Medium Range [1-100]
Level 3: Hard Range [1-1000]

Enter Level Number: 1
Difficulty level is set to 1

Please guess the number: 6

Sorry but the number you are trying to guess is lower that your guess
Already guessed numbers: [6]
Please guess the number: 2

Sorry but the number you are trying to guess is higher that your guess
Already guessed numbers: [6, 2]
Please guess the number: 5

Congratulations you have guessed the number on your number 3 attempt
Do you want to play again? Enter yes or no: yes

Round 2
Welcome to High Low game.
Please enter difficulty level.
Level 1: Easy Range [1-10]
Level 2: Medium Range [1-100]
Level 3: Hard Range [1-1000]

Enter Level Number: 1
Difficulty level is set to 1

Please guess the number: 1

Congratulations you have guessed the number on your number 1 attempt
Do you want to play again? Enter yes or no: no

Your average number of guesses are 2.0
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining the other method and how it works?

Comment: @Rezvan You mean calculate average? It is just adding all elements in list and dividing it by list size.

Comment: care to explain the " Integer mark: list and what sum += mark; means

Comment: @Rezvan Oh that is just advance for loop. I'll add explanation in answer.

Comment: Hi @Rezvan if this answer has helped you please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hey Thanks and Sure, Also just want to say that I have found a better way to do the game which I think is easier.